# Is Firebase unauth() codes correct?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, logout

I use Firebase for my app. When I segue back from a page to Login page and in prepareForSegue to logout the user, the page DOES go to login page but comes back to former page automatically right away. I want to make sure codes for logout are correct. Here are the codes:.  Ref_URLBASE is my app ref in Firebase.

```
@IBAction func backBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toLoginPage", sender: self)


    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {



    if segue.identifier == "toLoginPage" {

        Ref_URLBASE.unauth()
    }
```

Comment: It is likely code in your login page controller causing an autologin if you have implemented keychain access for username/password? Make sure this gets cleared after logout so that it doesn't auto log them in right after they logged out.

Comment: You are right, Thanks! I solved the problem. Can you put it as an answer so I can accept? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely code in your login page controller causing an autologin if you have implemented keychain access for username/password. Make sure this gets cleared after logout so that it doesn't auto log them in right after they logged out.